# reverse function to apply specific column in csv through shell reading

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sh

How to reverse a specific condition of 10th column data in csv.
input file:

```
RFIN0010|TD|379410|3261664|44753406|CAD|MC|SALE|S|4|8275.08|USD|0.76644909
RFIN0010|TD|379410|3261666|44753408|CAD||IA|S||-335.81|USD|
RFIN0010|TD|379410|3261666|44753408|CAD||PFEE|S||-15.31|USD|
HFIN0010T|362051|11/01/2017|11/01/2017|11/02/2017|08:55:43
RFIN0011|PFEE|DEP|TD|379410|3261666|44753408|USD|27366020|MC||"Fee"|S|4|0.0000|6342.43|0.000500|-3.18|CAD
HACT0010|362051|11/01/2017|11/01/2017|11/02/2017|08:48:41
RACT0010|11/01/2017|871889|"online3"|"1238"|12152|TD|349239|USD|"abc87905"||xxx01|06/20|12.00|VI|DP|10/31/2017|88450G|100||||7311||||||V383|N|.1|.0225|-.37|-.02||USD|""|
```

i want RACT0010 10th column data reverse

output:

```
 RFIN0010|TD|379410|3261664|44753406|CAD|MC|SALE|S|4|8275.08|USD|0.76644909
 RFIN0010|TD|379410|3261666|44753408|CAD||IA|S||-335.81|USD|
 RFIN0010|TD|379410|3261666|44753408|CAD||PFEE|S||-15.31|USD|   
 HFIN0010T|362051|11/01/2017|11/01/2017|11/02/2017|08:55:43

 RFIN0011|PFEE|DEP|TD|379410|3261666|44753408|USD|27366020|MC||"Fee"|S|4|0.0000|6342.43|0.000500|-3.18|CAD
 HACT0010|362051|11/01/2017|11/01/2017|11/02/2017|08:48:41
    RACT0010|11/01/2017|871889|"online3"|"1238"|12152|TD|349239|USD|"50978cba"||xxx01|06/20|12.00|VI|DP|10/31/2017|88450G|100||||7311||||||V383|N|.1|.0225|-.37|-.02||USD|""|
```

my shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
for j in *.dfr;
do
FILE=$j;
echo $j++ |awk '{if ($1=="RACT0010"){$10=reverse$10} else {$1=$1} print}' FS='|' OFS='|' $j> rev/$j
done;
```

Comment: I made a start at editing your question to improve the formatting but you should [edit] it yourself to make it clear, in particular the output.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `FILE=$j` (the onl place FILE is referenced in your script) and also with `echo $j++` (especially the increment)?

Answer (score 1):

The awk part of your problem can be solved like this (line breaks and comments added for clarity):

```
awk '$1 == "RACT0010" {              # use a condition, not an "if"
  n = split($10, a, //)              # split into array of characters
  s = ""                             # initialise s to empty
  for (i = n; i > 0; i--) s = s a[i] # build new reversed string
  $10 = s                            # overwrite original field
} 
1' FS='|' OFS='|' file               # 1 is shortest true condition
```

Putting this into your loop:

```
for j in *.dfr; do
    awk '$1 == "RACT0010" { 
      n = split($10, a, //); s = ""; for (i = n; i > 0; i--) s = s a[i]; $10 = s 
    } 1' FS='|' OFS='|' "$j" > rev/"$j"
done
```

As pointed out in the comments, using `split` with `//` isn't guaranteed by the spec to split the string into individual characters. In GNU awk it works, but in others it might not. An alternative method to reverse the string would be to use repeated calls to `substr`:

```
s = ""
len = length($10)
for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) s = s substr($10, len - i, 1)
```

Comment: @Prem I'm pleased to hear it. I recommend you check out the guide on what to do when [someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p rev
for j in *.dfr
do
    awk '{if ($1=="RACT0010"){x=""; for(i=length($10); i!=0; i--) {x=x substr($10, i, 1)}; $10=x}; print}' FS='|' OFS='|' $j > rev/$j
done
```